# wkhtmltopdf - html to pdf remove left and bottom white space

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, wkhtmltopdf, phpwkhtmltopdf

I am trying to generate a PDF from HTML, everything is working fine except there is a white space at bottom-left of the generated PDF.

I am using `wkhtmltopdf` library.

#### Here is my code :

```php
$globaloptions = array(
    'page-size' => 'A4',
    'margin-top' => '0',
    'margin-right' => '0',
    'margin-bottom' => '0',
    'margin-left' => '0',
    'encoding' => "UTF-8",
    'no-outline',
    'orientation' => 'Landscape',
    'enable-javascript',
);
$pdf = new Pdf;
$pdf->setOptions($globaloptions);
```

[image]